# Update table two from comparison on table one, bigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, sql-update

I'm trying to update a table in bigquery, using standardSQL but get the following error: Query error: Cannot execute IN subquery with uncomparable types STRING and INT64 at [81:7]

In essence, I have two tables. Table(a) and table(b). I am trying to update a column (boolean column) in table(b) when a particular record (flight_number) is found in table(b) and not in table(a).

```
UPDATE `HTZ_Analysis.airport_flightrecord` as tableb
SET table(b).In_Airport = False 
WHERE table(b).flight_number NOT IN (SELECT 1 
                                   FROM table(a)
                                  )
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the table's schemas for the columns you are comparing. It seems as if the column types differ, one being STRING and another one INT64. I guess that probably some flight numbers would contain letters, so I would [change the column type](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-table-schemas) to STRING in both columns. Then they should be comparable.